# I can't pass a String array to my AsyncTask

Tags: android

The compiler error is "`The method execute(ArrayList<String>...) in the type AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>,Void,ArrayList<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String)`"

Why wouldn't it accept the new parameter? can anyone see what i am doing wrong?

```
   ArrayList<String> passing = new ArrayList<String>();
            passing.add(logicalUrl);
            passing.add("filename.pdf");
            new myTask().execute(logicalUrl);
            return true;
        }

    public class myTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(ModuleContents.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Downloading...");
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.show();
        }

        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... passing) {
            ArrayList<String> passed = passing[0];
            String physicalUrl = parsePhysicalUrl(passed.get(0));
            String filename = passed.get(1);
            try {
                globals.saveFile(physicalUrl, filename);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return passed;

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `new myTask().execute(logicalUrl)` logicalUrl is `String` but you specified in generic that should be `ArrayList<String>`

So change it to

```
 public class myTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {}
```

or add as argument of your class `ArrayList` that you created.

```
new myTask().execute(passing);
```

and now it should work. It seems you only overlooked it :]

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
new myTask().execute(logicalUrl);
```

To:

```
new myTask().execute(passing);
```

Answer (score 1):

`new myTask().execute(passing);` instead of `new myTask().execute(logicalUrl);`

Answer (score 1):

Your method should like this

```
 ArrayList<String> passing = new ArrayList<String>();
        passing.add(logicalUrl);
        passing.add("filename.pdf");

        **new myTask().execute(passing);**

        return true;
```

And Check this link.,. its similara to your question

[Passing arguments to AsyncTask, and returning results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195609/passing-arguments-to-asynctask-and-returning-results)