# get arraylist values passed to asynctask at doinbackground

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-asynctask

I have an Asynctask setup I pass an Arraystring like this

```
ArrayList<String> creds = new ArrayList<String>();
creds.add(string1);
creds.add(string2);
new myasynctask().execute(creds);
```

**asynctask method**
class myasynctask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList, Integer , String>

**DOinbackground**

```
protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... creds) 

            {       String lol1= creds[0].toString();
                    String lol2= creds[1].toString();
........rest of the code
                                
}
```

I get an Array index out of bond exception
how do I pass tow values into the doinbackground method and get both of them at once.

Comment: could you differentiate between "creds" and "credentials"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get value by this code

```
class test extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, Void>
{

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... creds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str1 = creds[0].get(0);
    String str2 = creds[0].get(1);

    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the arraylist value,

```
 ArrayList<String> recList= new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arrayListVal= creds[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

get arraylist as in  `doInBackground` method of AsyncTask :

```
private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, String> {

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {

       ArrayList<String>  lol1= params[0]; //<< here retrieve Array from  varargs
      return null;
      }      
         // your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following link

[Passing arguments to AsyncTask, and returning results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195609/passing-arguments-to-asynctask-and-returning-results)

```
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... passing) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> passed = passing[0]; //get passed arraylist

        //Some calculations...

        return result; //return result
```