# My app crashes when the screen is locked

Tags: android

I have this in my **Logcat:**

```
threadid=1 thread exiting with uncaught exception FATAL EXCENPTION : main
```

In fact i used a thread to send a http request and a UI thread.

Comment: Please add Complete logtrace ....

Comment: Are you doing the network communications on `AysncTask` and how have you defined your `onPause` callback?

Comment: thanks for this faster response, in fact i don't have defined my onPause callback. What is it? sorry i'm a noob Android developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android implements only single thread environments. So if you try to communicate main thread from any separated thread from main UI thread this kind of error is obvious thing. you can use asynctask to do this

Comment: I have a problem if i want to use Async task. In fact i recovered a geo position with onLocationChanged, and i want to send the longitude and latitude with http request to google and add the response in an Edittext.How can i send arguments to my AsyncTask class? on the doInBackground() method?

Comment: @johnnyBeGood you can do it as , [This Example Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195609/passing-arguments-to-asynctask-and-returning-results) and [This Explained Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053602/what-arguments-are-passed-into-asynctaskarg1-arg2-arg3)